# Should the examples and big lists tags be the same?

Tags: discussion, tags

Independently on how good or relevant are this type questions, frequently there are questions looking for as many examples as possible of some historical happening or some type of personalities. Usual tags I have seen are [examples](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples) and [big-list](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list). For me these two are taken as the same. Asking (just for the example) "what are some examples of scientists with dogs?" would lead to examples but also many responses listing cases.

Is there a difference between the two? And if not, should both be merged into [examples](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples)?